# git detached worktree commit changes

Tags: git

For website development I have a git repository on a live server, that I cloned to a dev server, that I cloned to my own PC for local development.

The repository on the dev server is a bare repository, that has a detached worktree that is checked out with a post-receive hook (to keep the git repository outside the public_html folder):

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $1)
GIT_WORK_TREE=somepath/public_html git checkout -f $branch
```

I would usually do all work on my worksstation then push to dev and from there to live. Now there were some changes (updates) that were a lot easier to do on the dev server then on my pc. 
But how / or can I at all commit those changes, even though its a bare repo?

Comment: Have you considered cloning (typical, without --bare) the bare repo on another directory of the server then working on this one?

Comment: ~> clone repository, copy files, push to bare repo? Sounds like it could be a plan..

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would have gone for in the situation myself, glad you liked the idea. I'm putting this in a short answer, mostly for permanence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go as follows :

- in another directory on your server, clone the repo without the `--bare` parameter to have full capabilities on the clone (namely, a working tree)
- set your bare repo as remote for the new clone
- do whatever modifications you need on the clone
- push to original bare repo